# Show only certain portions of image inside a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I only show the image inside the div? Please refer to image below wherein only part of the image inside the blue highlighted part should be visible while the one boxed in red should not be shown leaving a space between images.

[image]

Output would be the image below.
[image]

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ee8hkxsd/1/).

I've pasted the code here as well.

```css
.img-sub {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-sub img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row grid-container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="row img-container img-featured">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <a href="/posts/1">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="img-container">
              <div class="col-md-4 img-sub">
                <a href="/posts/1">
                  <img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 img-sub">
                <a href="/posts/1">
                  <img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 img-sub">
                <a href="/posts/1">
                  <img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="img-container">
              <div class="col-md-4 img-sub">
                <a href="/posts/1">
                  <img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 img-sub">
                <a href="/posts/1">
                  <img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 img-sub">
                <a href="/posts/1">
                  <img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete as you may notice, the images are too close together. Check the second image I pasted here wherein there are spaces in between images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overflow:hidden also fills the padding that bootstrap uses to add the gutters.

So I moved the img-sub to the `<a>` element (also fixed up some css)

https://jsfiddle.net/y573zfja/3/

HTML:

```
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/posts/1" class="img-sub"><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/posts/1" class="img-sub"><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/posts/1" class="img-sub"><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/posts/1" class="img-sub"><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/posts/1" class="img-sub"><img class="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JPA_rzHDy6o/maxresdefault.jpg" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-sub {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.img-sub img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: -50%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clip` property to remove a part of the image :

```
clip:rect(0, 220px, 150px, 50px);
```

see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dp52dv2p/

and how to use clip : http://www.zonecss.fr/proprietes-css/clip-css.html

Comment: Though this works on my end but I wonder if there would be any browser issues when using clip?

Comment: Not that i know until you use `rect(...)`,

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS change this:

```
.img-sub img {
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0 auto;
      left: -100%;
      right: -100%;
      width: auto;
    }
```

To this:

```
.img-sub img {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```